# Uploading umbrella framework to cocoapods repository

Tags: ios, cocoapods

We are trying to upload our 2 framework projects to cocoapods. I've created the neccesary podspec files  for both frameworks and pushed it to cocoapods with using **pod trunk push command** 
In the first project there is no error because it doesnt depend on any other framework etc.. ( https://github.com/Kandy-IO/test-wrtc)

But in the second project there are lots of errors because that framework is dependend on some other sub frameworks which are already inside the actual framework folder (You can check our infrastructure from here: https://github.com/Kandy-IO/test-cp  , the subframeworks are in subframeworks folder)

I've created the below podspec file for this framework:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|  
    s.name              = 'CPaaSSDK'
    s.version           = '1.6.6'
    s.summary           = 'CpaasSDK'
    s.homepage          = 'https://github.com/Kandy-IO/test-cp'
    s.license       = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'mit-license.txt'}
    s.author            = { 'Name' => 'tolgat@xxxxx.com.tr' }

    s.platform          = :ios
    s.source            = { :git => 'https://github.com/Kandy-IO/test-cp.git', :tag => '1.6.6'}
    s.dependency    'CPaaSWebRTC'
    s.public_header_files      = "CPaaSSDK.framework/Headers/*.h", "CPaaSSDK.framework/SubFrameworks/**/Headers/*.h"
    s.ios.deployment_target   = '9.0'
    s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'CPaaSSDK.framework'
end
```

And when I try to push the podspec file , it gives the following error. What should I do to get rid of these errors.
Note: Our subframeworks are mixed (Some of them are objc and some of them are swift), the actual framework which we try to push is an umbralle framework

```
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftsimd'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: 
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftAVFoundation'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMedia'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'RestManager'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'CPAddressBookService'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'CPPresenceService'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'CPAuthenticationService'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'NotificationEngine'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'CPMessagingService'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'CPCallService'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'CPPushService'
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  RestManager.CPRestDownloadRequest.completion(_: __C.NSObject?, error: Swift.Error?) -> () in CPaaSSDK(CPRestDownloadRequest.o)
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  function signature specialization <Arg[1] = Exploded> of CPAddressBookService.CPAddressBookService.(logResult in _FFF4592E3450CC7F075A904CF3818DC2)(error: __C.CPError?, functionName: Swift.String) -> () in CPaaSSDK(CPAddressBookService.o)
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked library 'swiftCoreAudio'
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'CPWebRTC'
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'CPUtilities'
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are the github repos still live? I tried to check the infrastructure but the links give a 404 error